# Xamarin App secure web server login

Tags: security, web, xamarin, server

I am quite new to the world of Xamarin and mobile development, but have been asked to create a simple cross-platform mobile app which is able to log into a secure web server, download some SQL data and then display it in the app.

What I am trying to understand is how to get the mobile app to request the data from my web server securly. I've seen and read a lot of information about requesting data from a web server using HttpWebRequest, but none of the examples describe how to secure this data. Also I see a lot of info about creating a REST API, but again I am not sure if thats the way I need to go?

Can anyone give me a really simple breakdown of the steps I will need to implement in order to achieve this? I feel like I'm drowning in a sea of web technologies and not sure which way to swim :)

I will be using IIS as the database and the Xamarin App will need to run on both iOS and Android.

Any help greatly appreciated!

Mike

Comment: If you want anything secure, I would say go with `HTTPS`/`SSL` and `OAUTH` and then that would mean that you would use a `REST` API.

Comment: Also, there are components (Free, paid and self written) that can encrypt the `SQLite` database you use to store the data.

Comment: Definitely go with HTTPS - iOS 9 actually requires this (without declaring exemptions).  Are you writing the app and web service?  If so, what sort of authentication scheme do you need to use?  Company logins?  Custom user accounts?  C# Web API can support most of these sorts of authentication out of the box and provide OAuth access.

Comment: Cool, thanks. I am going to be writing the app and I can write the web service if needs be. My thinking was that I create a simple db table with username/password per user that is used to authenticate the users prior to being able to access the rest of the data.

Comment: I would suggest not storing a table of usernames and passwords on the device.

Comment: @MikeB I would encourage you not to re-invent the wheel.  Use a pre-built authentication system.  Microsoft has some pretty good pre-built stuff that will get baked into a new Visual Studio project.

Comment: @Dylan S. I'm all for doing things the right way. Could you point me in the direction of a tutorial or docs regarding pre-built authentication? Thanks!

Comment: @MikeB http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/tutorial-your-first-web-api is a good starter on Web API and http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/individual-accounts-in-web-api has some great background on authentication in Web API.  The last one is primarily a JavaScript based client, but it all applies to a mobile client as well.

Comment: @Dylan S. Thanks for the suggestions! I will check those out and see how they work. Cheers!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It´s a bit confusing the way you want to implement this and the level of security you need. There are many techniques to secure your app and your server. Some are easy to implement and others not so easy.

What I understand is that your application will be hosted on IIS. There is no such thing as a IIS database. IIS is just an application server by Microsoft.

The most common technology hosted in IIS is Asp.NET and Microsoft SQL Server database. But others can be used, like php (installing some extensions) and mysql server. Anyway, using just php in IIS is a bad decision IMO, as there many other light weight and better servers to do that.

Xamarin has nothing to do with server security. Xamarin is just a client technology and the security must reside on your server application. 
That said, there are many good practices you should follow to make clients more secure:

1. Never store user passwords or sensible data on a local store (device database, settings, file system, etc)
2. As others suggested, send your data to the server through https protocol (SSL must be configured on the server side)
3. If you must save critical data on the device, use an encryption
   algorithm (there are tons of libraries to encrypt local SQL
   databases, just google it)

In case you go for Asp.NET I suggest that you go ahead and integrate [Asp.Net Identity](http://www.asp.net/identity). It´s the standard authentication/authorization system for ASP.Net and the built-in features will handle you user database as well as security issues you would hardly find out by yourself (ie: storing passwords "as is" in the database is a big security hole)

Afterwards, you will have to choose an authentication (login) system. There are multiple choices but the industry standard would be [oAuth2](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/an-introduction-to-oauth-2). Use refresh tokens if you want to make oAuth2 more secure. oAuth is supported by Asp.Net identity and Xamarin. For Xamarin you can use an oAuth .NET client library or make simple http calls (HttpWebRequest) to request tokens, refresh tokens, etc.

About [REST API](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer): I think that´s the way to go, no matter what client or server stack you´re using. Again, Asp.NET has a [WebApi](http://www.asp.net/web-api) that will enable REST on your application.

If all this sounds like too much, don´t worry. When you create an Asp.Net application in Visual Studio using a template, you will get a ready app with REST (WebApi) and authentication/authorization/security (Asp.Net Identity) by default.

It´s important that you implement oAuth correctly both in the server and the client side. Otherwise you could face some security problems

Comment: thank you for such an in-depth resonse and clear descriptions. I will start to investigate each of the systems you have suggested, it certainly looks like this is the approach I want to take.